# BigQuery JDBC driver arrays and structs

Tags: google-bigquery, logstash

I use Logstash with Simba JDBC driver to get data from BigQuery. According to documentation arrays should be brought back as JSON representation of that data, but this doesn't seem to be the case as I'm getting that in a ruby debug form.

https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/features/arrays.htm

That's my query

```sql
SELECT categoryid, categoryname, skucount, filters, lastupdate, deleted
FROM migration_search.categories
ORDER BY lastupdate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And it does bring back the following data.

```json
{
  "category": {
    "id": 200802,
    "name": "Chia seeds"
  },
  "skuCount": 1024,
  "filters": "[{v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2755512}, {v=19317}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2840491}, {v=20406}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2090516}, {v=7717}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=375}, {v=294509}, {v=4452}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=550665}, {v=806}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2581186}, {v=3831}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=276}, {v=17635}, {v=724}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2752211}, {v=3533}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2548726}, {v=25386}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2083921}, {v=46736}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=357709}, {v=4731}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=691821}, {v=46463}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=577090}, {v=950}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2079230}, {v=27771}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2713301}, {v=33862},{v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2347802}, {v=26186}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=283485}, {v=45215}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=141070}, {v=5028}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2581782}, {v=45754}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=20613}, {v=4965}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=364}, {v=33369}, {v=4543}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=519912}, {v=4350}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=191}, {v=295774}, {v=798}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=690769}, {v=11166}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2545756}, {v=15379}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=259087}, {v=5049}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2479029}, {v=5134}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=555122}, {v=21016}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2115318}, {v=836}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2684050}, {v=26980}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=523629}, {v=55757}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2627565}, {v=6637}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2752211}, {v=3533}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2732723}, {v=21391}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=2033975}, {v=337}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=220231}, {v=11071}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=179521}, {v=4952}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2243454}, {v=9933}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=474755}, {v=4720}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=356559}, {v=5870}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=266005}, {v=9431}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2752211}, {v=3533}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=238246}, {v=7105}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2805489}, {v=47333}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=680897}, {v=9728}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2546446}, {v=1091}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=2257294}, {v=2324}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2570913}, {v=36905}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2283176}, {v=10953}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=117748}, {v=6960}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=437444}, {v=15250}, {v=CH}]}},{v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=471579}, {v=4998}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=265532}, {v=10978}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=276}, {v=2215691}, {v=957}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2563793}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2695617}, {v=1915}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2684782}, {v=12791}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2150139}, {v=2374}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=2470217}, {v=19381}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=375}, {v=305691}, {v=2795}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2581782}, {v=45754}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=170}, {v=186080}, {v=55222}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2561051}, {v=23623}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2619326}, {v=6860}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2770288}, {v=9912}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=2322099}, {v=3228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=193}, {v=412065}, {v=7753}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=276}, {v=2832464}, {v=27959}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=393}, {v=2064468}, {v=22256}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=414910}, {v=12950}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2508698}, {v=59621}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=2647293}, {v=52750}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802},{v=380}, {v=2686590}, {v=24755}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=2854402}, {v=2337}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=329343}, {v=5964}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=180232}, {v=16088}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2541782}, {v=16245}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=472801}, {v=2798}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=156365}, {v=44666}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=172758}, {v=9616}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=692479}, {v=5681}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2800621}, {v=37053}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2009976}, {v=1748}, {v=CH}]}},{v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2427188}, {v=14411}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=35905}, {v=4937}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2636387}, {v=11672}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=143701}, {v=3376}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=520600}, {v=3461}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2521331}, {v=4652}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=364}, {v=2700903}, {v=20039}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2136311}, {v=46095}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=276}, {v=113523}, {v=1543}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=329635}, {v=4639}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2684051}, {v=26980}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=320266}, {v=6524}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=273}, {v=178291}, {v=944}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=294509}, {v=4452}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=128466}, {v=6479}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2488322}, {v=36793}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=358999}, {v=15658}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=280}, {v=2001377}, {v=814}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=520600}, {v=3461}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=2343494}, {v=53628}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=616074}, {v=13340}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=296578}, {v=972}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=280}, {v=2003934}, {v=7144}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2398758}, {v=37673}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2364397}, {v=39341}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=2581782}, {v=45754}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=2866299}, {v=31648}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=280}, {v=2004954}, {v=814}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802},{v=243}, {v=686586}, {v=2372}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=191}, {v=2686045}, {v=46507}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2640101}, {v=29194}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=464722}, {v=10262}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2115895}, {v=41700}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2474110}, {v=829}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2546910}, {v=7741}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2713307}, {v=22499}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2563792}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2837772}, {v=2609}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2701669}, {v=10398}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=254}, {v=2751142}, {v=4430}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=318992}, {v=4511}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=167}, {v=2701669}, {v=10398}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=71074}, {v=8828}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2437889}, {v=28513}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2309711}, {v=26100}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=435054}, {v=928}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=579917}, {v=5302}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=180232}, {v=16088}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2151314}, {v=48814}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2548341}, {v=42747}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=128488}, {v=6529}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=700984}, {v=8144}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2632015}, {v=21272}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=680536}, {v=4242}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2630230}, {v=7355}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=145254}, {v=5870}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2548328}, {v=14399}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2333430}, {v=25445}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2560723}, {v=24014}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2099116}, {v=50780}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2000533}, {v=253}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2701669}, {v=10398}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2626202}, {v=37111}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=612183}, {v=19161}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=306520}, {v=846}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=571339}, {v=15562}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2151280}, {v=12511}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=2345726}, {v=3702}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2563793}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=294509}, {v=4452}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=572604}, {v=4717}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=2467288}, {v=53297}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2565789}, {v=51815}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=550460}, {v=20790}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2866431}, {v=1865}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2352675}, {v=4515}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=519912}, {v=4350}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2678927}, {v=15095}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=180057}, {v=45001}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=186126}, {v=4121}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=473196}, {v=6850}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=273}, {v=544074}, {v=3249}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2186913}, {v=25707}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=259847}, {v=15491}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=615116},{v=6154}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2473009}, {v=21442}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=538507}, {v=950}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2111674}, {v=14572}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2632015}, {v=21272}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=426411}, {v=57137}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=700735}, {v=2983}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=2470217}, {v=19381}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=322}, {v=550460}, {v=20790}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=240611}, {v=19188}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2356379}, {v=25454}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=375}, {v=669168}, {v=626}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=180058}, {v=446}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2801396}, {v=25799}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=549671}, {v=16167}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2205033}, {v=15857}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=198326}, {v=16025}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=2660990}, {v=54811}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2795987}, {v=23006}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2498336}, {v=21524}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2470217}, {v=19381}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2673664}, {v=20274}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=393}, {v=406163}, {v=62511}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2564605}, {v=16912}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=265121}, {v=8506}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=619815}, {v=56115}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=276}, {v=2402484}, {v=3226}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=180232}, {v=16088}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2751371}, {v=21287}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=195}, {v=692799}, {v=15466}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=2452177}, {v=4340}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2688613}, {v=3983}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=695192}, {v=20933}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=353141}, {v=2152}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2110472}, {v=4951}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=641887}, {v=9484}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=320}, {v=260184}, {v=61086}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=2796744}, {v=54948}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=538049}, {v=46880}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=642296}, {v=12288}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2151271}, {v=26679}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2267298}, {v=18149}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=468099}, {v=48627}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=259}, {v=2774696}, {v=28450}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=348}, {v=2681618}, {v=5577}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2608806}, {v=46279}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=259}, {v=2563792}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=126797}, {v=1943}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=191}, {v=180593}, {v=22357}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2078976}, {v=25315}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=370829}, {v=12190}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=259}, {v=2752211}, {v=3533}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2151294}, {v=9251}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=195}, {v=2832480}, {v=22641}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=686191}, {v=6225}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=205}, {v=144746}, {v=46485}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2291526}, {v=43403}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2686045}, {v=46507}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=170}, {v=405919}, {v=4990}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=213741}, {v=54873}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2612243}, {v=51954}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2494081}, {v=24729}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=411962}, {v=46098}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2755980}, {v=7384}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2796000}, {v=2588}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2495272}, {v=26436}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=170}, {v=499646}, {v=3232}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=692799}, {v=15466}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=612183}, {v=19161}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=474550}, {v=4731}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=174}, {v=627324}, {v=12288}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=144438}, {v=4452}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2653011}, {v=444}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=405541}, {v=4731}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2151280}, {v=12511}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2732732}, {v=21391}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2678381}, {v=21284}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=660151}, {v=4977}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802},{v=264}, {v=2548341}, {v=42747}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2653895}, {v=20374}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=193}, {v=2514677}, {v=8810}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=304079}, {v=2449}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=483981}, {v=6394}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2548727}, {v=25386}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2291419}, {v=61836}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2363756}, {v=29686}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=375}, {v=520600}, {v=3461}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=693115}, {v=4937}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=421385}, {v=19876}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2617612}, {v=3376}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=555122}, {v=21016}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2581053}, {v=25877}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2562846}, {v=25394}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=170}, {v=2774696}, {v=28450}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2859528}, {v=26505}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2018586}, {v=8851}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=427984}, {v=57929}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=320}, {v=627324}, {v=12288}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2752211}, {v=3533}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=642296}, {v=12288}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2486027}, {v=7248}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=648140}, {v=44702}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2304560}, {v=6268}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2497407}, {v=2268}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=128462}, {v=48579}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2470217}, {v=19381}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=593233}, {v=6369}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=468876}, {v=184}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=259}, {v=414910}, {v=12950}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=303512}, {v=3501}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=472836}, {v=20894}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=167}, {v=2291807}, {v=2668}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802},{v=380}, {v=2563792}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=191}, {v=122259}, {v=5754}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=405392}, {v=444}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2078117}, {v=1088}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2532271}, {v=3999}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=2220945}, {v=8561}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=198326}, {v=16025}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2313970}, {v=3645}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=213741}, {v=54873}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=553851}, {v=6183}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2719091}, {v=2423}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=563253}, {v=6770}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=359221}, {v=46099}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=2548341}, {v=42747}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2314721}, {v=19587}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2748810}, {v=19108}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2627565}, {v=6637}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=338419}, {v=18750}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=512114}, {v=419}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2563792}, {v=13228}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2774696}, {v=28450}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=322}, {v=571981}, {v=60465}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=578821}, {v=2724}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=423205}, {v=60780}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2151313}, {v=9251}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=393606}, {v=18976}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2057623}, {v=17375}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=680897}, {v=9728}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2627565}, {v=6637}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=2314721}, {v=19587}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=555319}, {v=1154}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=167},{v=457055}, {v=2353}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=2182541}, {v=17427}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=122259}, {v=5754}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2561809}, {v=4624}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=427253}, {v=60549}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2548341}, {v=42747}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=171445}, {v=12275}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2347703}, {v=4480}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=364}, {v=2097386}, {v=3799}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=693425}, {v=4121}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=414865}, {v=15513}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2684054}, {v=26980}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=56518}, {v=4121}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2774696}, {v=28450}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=194278}, {v=4135}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2407562}, {v=37589}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=514670}, {v=15503}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=520600}, {v=3461}, {v=CH}]}},{v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=557066}, {v=178}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2684051}, {v=26980}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=446125}, {v=10836}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=421367}, {v=39304}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=320}, {v=642296}, {v=12288}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=371434}, {v=11179}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=580983}, {v=46100}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=145235}, {v=24084}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2328121}, {v=3094}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=2548341}, {v=42747}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=520600}, {v=3461}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2747531}, {v=45341}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=238246}, {v=7105}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=585810}, {v=28944}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=635567}, {v=3381}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=2254444}, {v=10521}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=586895}, {v=15898}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2548727}, {v=25386}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=375}, {v=612183}, {v=19161}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2581100}, {v=21504}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=2590422}, {v=28248}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=187}, {v=2375428}, {v=13893}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=2770104}, {v=6069}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802},{v=191}, {v=265121}, {v=8506}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=351}, {v=329673}, {v=3580}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=534027}, {v=1347}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=259}, {v=267578}, {v=16082}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2390434}, {v=18659}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=224902}, {v=480}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=550460}, {v=20790}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=405528}, {v=8405}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=302687}, {v=12863}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=2546223}, {v=29243}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=642374}, {v=2624}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=65018}, {v=13376}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=182}, {v=2729614}, {v=2338}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=245}, {v=450068}, {v=15472}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=368}, {v=160850}, {v=60764}, {v=CH}]}},{v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=414910}, {v=12950}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=214}, {v=701446}, {v=1904}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=380}, {v=637523}, {v=12150}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=294509}, {v=4452}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=352}, {v=2291451}, {v=46038}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=191}, {v=212248}, {v=46025}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=212}, {v=2468725}, {v=4149}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2545155}, {v=18629}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2324326}, {v=51038}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=2684000}, {v=1123}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=263}, {v=2701472}, {v=5441}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=625038}, {v=55787}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=265}, {v=411959}, {v=1826}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=262322}, {v=5688}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=240}, {v=550460}, {v=20790}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=243}, {v=2532156}, {v=47377}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=240}, {v=331677}, {v=2724}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=264}, {v=2770104}, {v=6069}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=240}, {v=550271}, {v=54750}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=313}, {v=397191}, {v=4965}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=236}, {v=198327}, {v=5691}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=344}, {v=519912}, {v=4350}, {v=CH}]}}, {v={f=[{v=200802}, {v=333}, {v=680657}, {v=4052}, {v=CH}]}}]"
}
```

I do not make any transformations on filters column and I'd like it to have filters in a JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to configure JDBC driver to do this for me, so I have used `TO_JSON_STRING` built in BigQuery function:

```sql
SELECT categoryid
  , categoryname
  , skucount
  , TO_JSON_STRING(filters) AS filters
  , lastupdate
  , deleted
FROM migration_search.categories
ORDER BY lastupdate DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Even though it's not the way I'd prefer to do this, it works.